# Display time format in a running stopwatch

Tags: javascript

I'm making a stopwatch and out of esthetic reasons I want the output to display: 00:00:00:000. The problem is that when my stopwatch is running I'm having a hard time getting it to except a 0 in front when the value < 10.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

var display = document.getElementById('display-area');
var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle-button');
var reset = document.getElementById('reset-button');

var ms,
  difference,
  interval,
  hours,
  minutes,
  seconds,
  timer = 0;

function start() {
  difference = Date.now();
  interval = window.setInterval(update, 10);
  timer = 1;
};

function stopp() {
  window.clearInterval(interval);
  timer = 0;
};

function nullstill() {
ms = 0;
seconds = 0;
minutes = 0;
hours = 0;
display.value = '00:00:00:000';
};

function update() {
ms += elapsedTime();
if (ms >= 1000) {
  seconds += 1;
  ms = 0;
}
if (seconds >= 60) {
  minutes += 1;
  seconds = 0;
}
if (minutes >= 60) {
    hours += 1;
    minutes = 0;
}

display.value = hours + ':' + minutes +':' + seconds +':'+ ms;
};

function elapsedTime() {
var now = Date.now();
elapsed = now - difference;
difference = now;
return elapsed;
};

nullstill();

toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
console.log(timer);
if (timer != 1) {
  start();
} else {
  stopp();
}
});

reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
nullstill();
});

});
```

How do I make it work?

Regards,

Comment: Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: Posted the whole JS code now. HTML only consists of two buttons and an output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An integer will never hold a 0 in front of the number. This is a fairly easy fix. You will just need to use some string concatenation.

`display.value = (hours < 10 ? "0"+hours : hours) + ':' + (minutes < 10 ? "0"+minutes : minutes) +':' + (seconds < 10 ? "0"+seconds: seconds) +':'+ ms;`

The syntax I have used is called a ternary operator. Here is a little bit about how it works. Basically, it is a simplified if statement which can be used inline.

`( condition ? {if true, run this } : {else, run this})`

Comment: Thanks! Tried something similiar, but guess I didn't use it correctly.

Comment: I would avoid the long line and break it down into separate variables. I think it would look cleaner that way. Otherwise, nice answer

Answer (score 3):

Here's a useful little example that shows you a convenient way to add leading zeros to numbers in Javascript.  If you have a number like 53, and want 6 number places (eg 4 leading zeros in the case of 56), you just add `(1e6+53+'').slice(-6)` and that will give you `000053`  because 1e6 means 1 with 6 zeros after it, and slice with a negative number starts from the end and chops out 6 places in this case, so 100000053 becomes 000053

```js
hours=0,minutes=1,seconds=20,ms=7;

document.getElementById('t').innerHTML= 
  (1e2+hours+'').slice(-2) + ':' + 
  (1e2+minutes+'').slice(-2) +':' + 
  (1e2+seconds+'').slice(-2) +':'+ 
  (1e3+ms+'').slice(-3);
```

```html
<div id='t'></div>
```

Notice the 1 or 2 leading zeros in the case of ms is handled.  And you can adjust the number of leading zeros easily.

Comment: This is a really cool answer, thanks for sharing. I have never seen this before in JS. This also accounts for if the number is 0. Awesome.

Comment: @jbman223 it seems a bit unorthodox at first, but when you compare it to the typical (((x<10?...))) stuff it starts to grow on you, for many (not all) cases.

Answer (score 0):

This requires string concatenation when the value is less than 10. I would create three separate variables for the hours, minutes and seconds. That way the code is more clean and readable.

```
var displayHours = (hours >= 10) ? hours : "0" + hours;
var displayMins = (minutes >= 10) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
var displaySeconds = (seconds >= 10) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;

display.value = displayHours + displayMins + displaySeconds + ":" + ms;
```